# Generating random string valid for UTF-8 encode and decode

Tags: c#, string, random, utf-8, encode

For testing purpose, I need to generate a random string, which is then encoded into byte array for transferring over the Web and decoded back to a result string. The test uses NUnit framework to compare the original string with the result string. Since the encoded byte array has to be friendly for Web, it is encoded with UTF-8.

The string is encoded into a byte array by `Encoder.GetBytes` from `UTF8Encoding`. The byte array is decoded to string by `Decoder.GetChars` from `UTF8Encoding`.

The original string needs to be generated randomly and contain any sequence of characters, which can be encoded/decoded using UTF-8 encoding.

My first attempt to generate the string was:

```
   public static String RandomString(Random rnd, Int32 length) {
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(length);
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                 str.Append((char)rnd.Next(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue));
          return str.ToString();
   }
```

The above code produces strings with invalid sequences to encode.

I found some suggestions on the web and improved the code:

```
   public static String RandomString(Random rnd, Int32 length) {
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(length);
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                 char c = (char)rnd.Next(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue);
                 while (c >= 0xD800 && c <= 0xDFFF)
                        c = (char)rnd.Next(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue);
                 str.Append(c);
          return str.ToString();
   }
```

The above code has no problem with encoding, but decoding the byte array fails. Furthermore, I am not sure that the code can cover all possible cases.

Any suggestions, how to generate a random string with the given requirements in C#.

**UPD**: using a random string in encoding/decoding:

```
   public static Encoder Utf8Encode = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetEncoder();
   public static Decoder Utf8Decode = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetDecoder();

   public unsafe void TestString(Random rnd, int length, byte* byteArray, 
                 int arrayLenght) {
          int encodedLen;
          String str = RandomString(rnd, length);
          fixed (char* pStr = str) {
                 encodedLen = Utf8Encode.GetBytes(pStr, str.Length, byteArray,
                        arrayLenght, true);
          }
          char* buffer = stackalloc char[8192];
          int decodedLen = Utf8Decode.GetChars(byteArray, encodedLen, buffer, 
                 8192, true);
          String res = new String(buffer, 0, decodedLen);
          Assert.AreEqual(str, res);
   }
```

Comment: I don't think random strings are good way to unit test something, it theoretically breaks principle `Repeatable: Tests should produce the same results each time.. every time. Tests should not rely on uncontrollable params`. I think random tests are coming from laziness to create actual tests for edge cases.

Comment: The random generator is always created with the same sealed value, thus every time test runs the same result is produced, i.e., tests are repeatable.

Comment: If it's to be a valid Unicode string, you're better off with values only between U+0000 and U+D7FF, since there are other illegal values above U+E000 as well. Anyway, you say "decoding the byte array". Can you show the byte array? There's only UTF-16 strings in your example.

Comment: Certainly values above U+FFFF are necessary for any testing of Unicode. If it's just random noise, creating each character as a random element between 0 and 10FFFF and rejecting the surrogates and noncharacters. http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar4 lists all 66 of the latter. Then convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Excluding values above 0xE000 helped to resolve problem with failing decode.

Comment: The question is, what exactly was causing the decode to fail? That excludes a lot of the interesting values.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the code below for generating random UTF-8 character byte sequences. I can't guarantee it captures every aspect of the UTF-8 spec, but it was valuable for my testing purposes, so I'm posting it here.

```
private static readonly (int, int)[] HeadByteDefinitions =
{
    (1 << 7, 0b0000_0000),
    (1 << 5, 0b1100_0000),
    (1 << 4, 0b1110_0000),
    (1 << 3, 0b1111_0000)
};

static byte[] RandomUtf8Char(Random gen)
{
    const int totalNumberOfUtf8Chars = (1 << 7) + (1 << 11) + (1 << 16) + (1 << 21);
    int tailByteCnt;
    var rnd = gen.Next(totalNumberOfUtf8Chars);
    if (rnd < (1 << 7))
        tailByteCnt = 0;
    else if (rnd < (1 << 7) + (1 << 11))
        tailByteCnt = 1;
    else if (rnd < (1 << 7) + (1 << 11) + (1 << 16))
        tailByteCnt = 2;
    else
        tailByteCnt = 3;

    var (range, offset) = HeadByteDefinitions[tailByteCnt];
    var headByte = Convert.ToByte(gen.Next(range) + offset);
    var tailBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, tailByteCnt)
        .Select(_ => Convert.ToByte(gen.Next(1 << 6) + 0b1000_0000));

    return new[] {headByte}.Concat(tailBytes).ToArray();
}
```